# SharePoint Foundation 2013, branding search results page?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, css, search-results, branding

How I can brand search results page in SharePoint Foundation 2013?
I have brand other sites using custom.css file, however it dosen't work in search result page at all. What am I missing here? How I can change background etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search results page exist in a search template/web part. You can edit these and even create your own based on the standard templates.

To see all the default search display templates, `go to Site settings --> Master pages and page layouts. In the Master Page Gallery, click Display Templates --> Search.`

The following diagram is how it all hangs together.

[image]

The following blog post explains it all in full detail. The 2nd link is how to specifically create your own.

[Understanding how search results are displayed in SharePoint Server 2013](https://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2013/09/04/understand-how-search-results-are-displayed-in-sharepoint-server-2013.aspx)

[Customizing SharePoint 2013 Search Display Templates](http://sharepointfieldnotes.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/customizing-sharepoint-2013-search.html)

Comment: This is does not work in Foundation, only Server.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your css is loaded by the master page. You might have to set it again if your search is hosted in a sub site.

The search page layout can differ a lot from the default SharePoint layout. You might need to redo a bunch of the styling.